# Java indexOf - Array and objects

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package javaapplication10arraylistandobjects;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication10Arraylistandobjects {

    static Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test();

    }

    public static void test() {

        ArrayList<mainclass> me = new ArrayList<>();
        mainclass ob = new mainclass();

        System.out.println("name");
        ob.name = user_input.nextLine();

        me.add(new mainclass());

        // int index = me.indexOf(ob);
        System.out.println("new position" + me.indexOf(ob));

    }

}
```

---

```
package javaapplication10arraylistandobjects;

import java.util.Objects;

public class mainclass {

    String name;

    public mainclass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public mainclass() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 83 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final mainclass other = (mainclass) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

===output===
run:
name
jony
new position-1

## BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

When I am trying to find indexOf it shows me "-1".
I found some similar topics with the same problem where it says that I have 
to override equals() and hashcode(), I have done that as we can see but is still same problem.
Can someone explain or show me how to do correct.Thx

Comment: You are adding a `new mainclass()`. Not `ob`. That's why the `indexOf` is -1.

Comment: The two objects have different names, so are not equal. One has name null, the other has name whatever you entered.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you never add `ob` to your main class.

Try changing

```
 me.add(new mainclass());
```

to

```
 me.add(ob);
```